# Post JSON to mvc3 controller from WinForms App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms

I have a controller / action in an ASP.NET MVC3 app. It handles the post request for a user login. I am trying to simulate that but from a desktop winForms app.

My controller looks like this:

```
  [HttpPost]
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public virtual ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
  {
    //authenticate user logic
  }
```

I'm generating my HTTP request this way:

public static bool AuthenticateClient(Client client, string username, string password)
        {
            // change these field names to whatever elements your login page is expecting
            string usernameField = username;
            string passwordField = password;

```
        string loginUrl = "http://localhost/Account/LogOn/";

        // format login request
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(loginUrl);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        // format and send login data
        string requestData = JSON.Serialize(new LogOnModel(usernameField, passwordField, false));

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        sw.Write(requestData);
        sw.Close();

        // get the login response
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string responseData = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();

        // retrieve the session ID
        string sessionId = null;
        foreach (Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
        {
            if (cookie.Name == AuthCookieName)
            {
                sessionId = cookie.Value;
            }
        }

        // could not authenticate
        if (sessionId == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // send the session ID with every request
        client.OnRequestCreated = (args) =>
        {
            args.Request.Headers["Cookie"] = string.Format("{0}={1}", AuthCookieName, sessionId);
        };
        return true;
    }
```

Typically, I can make Ajax requests from jQuery and pass it the same object parameters that the Controller Action is expecting (the LogonModel in this case), however, when I do that from my desktop app, it's showing up as null for me each time in the action.

So my question is, how can I make the request from my desktop winforms app, and fill the object (LogonModel) in the controller so that I can authenticate?

Comment: Code Solution: 

 string requestData = string.Format("{0}={1}&{2}={3}&RememberMe=false&Login=Login", 
                "UserName", Uri.EscapeDataString(username),
                "Password", Uri.EscapeDataString(password));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(For completeness...)

You can never be too sure whether you are framing the request right. Personally I've found it easier to monitor and compare the calls using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) then refine and emulate as necessary...